# IsAntiAlias creates border around graph

Tags: c#, antialiasing, zedgraph

Here's screenshot of my form with a Zedgraph:

[image: http://eff1fan.com/antialias-false.png]

It's how I want it: grey graph on a grey form; no graph or chart borders. The only problem is the aliasing. So I add this:

```
zedGraphControl1.IsAntiAlias = true;
```

but then I get this:

[image: http://eff1fan.com/antialias-true.png]

How can I get rid of that partial border on the top and left of the graph that now appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zedgraphControl1.MasterPane.Border.IsVisible = false;
```

Should fix it.

Comment: ah.  "masterpane".  i didn't know that existed.  bless you.

Answer (score 1):

i dug around the zedgraph source; couldn't find any easy cause/fix.  so, i just turned off antialiasing for the whole graph (in the designer) and then turned it on for the individual components:

```
        myPane.XAxis.Title.FontSpec.IsAntiAlias = true;

        LineItem curve_x = new LineItem("x", x_values, sensor_x, Color.Red, SymbolType.None, 2.5F);
        LineItem curve_y = new LineItem("y", x_values, sensor_y, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None, 2.5F);
        LineItem curve_z = new LineItem("z", x_values, sensor_z, Color.Green, SymbolType.None, 2.5F);

        curve_x.Line.IsAntiAlias = true;
        curve_y.Line.IsAntiAlias = true;
        curve_z.Line.IsAntiAlias = true;

        myPane.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.IsAntiAlias = true;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.FontSpec.IsAntiAlias = true;
```

that did the trick.

http://www.eff1fan.com/antialias-workaround.png

Comment: Even if there turned out to be a better solution this is a clever workaround!