# ZedGraph to PDF using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, zedgraph, migradoc, drawtobitmap

I am currently working on a C# application that aims to do some computation and output graphs in a pdf file.

I use the Zedgraph library to draw my graphs so something like graphPane.AddCurve(PointPairList).  Now I tried to output these graphs to pdf file via MigraDoc package.

Currently, I have a script that map the Zedgraph to bitmap then paste it on the pdf file. So something like this:

```
private Bitmap getBitMap()
{

  ZedGraphControl graph = new ZedGraphControl();

  newGraph = graphPane.Clone();

  SizeF s = new SizeF(3.5f, 4.5f);
  newGraph.Scale(s);

  newGraph.DrawToBitmap(bit, new Rectangle(0, 0, newGraph.Width,    newGraph.Height));

  return bit;

}
```

The problem is that this give me a slightly pixellated image on the pdf page.  And I need this graph to be in a very high quality.  So are there anything I can change the improve the quality or do i have to change my entire approach for such thing.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a `Bitmap` you create has your current **screen resolution** which could be as low as `75dpi`, more common `96dpi`; more modern monitors have `120dpi` or more, but a good print quality starts `150dpi`. For really crips images you want `300dpi` and to allow zooming you may want to have `600dpi` or more..

So you need to create and fill a bitmap with a larger size and take control of its dpi resolution.

Assuming your size of `3.5f x 4.5f` is inches, for `300dpi` you need a `Bitmap` with `1050 x 1350` pixels.

So you should create such a `Bitmap`..:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1050, 1350);
```

..and **set** the resolution:

```
bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
```

To fill it up your control must have the same size:

```
newGraph.ClientSize = bmp.Size;
```

Now `DrawToBitmap` should create an image that is crisp and fit to zoom in..

Note that it does not matter if the control is too large to fit on the screen; `DrawToBitmap` will still work.

**Update** In addidtion to a sufficient resolution it is of interest to draw quality lines etc.. A speciality of ZedGraph is that one can turn on **Antialiasing**, either for individual lines:

```
curve_x.Line.IsAntiAlias = true;
```

or other elements:

```
myPane.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.IsAntiAlias = true;
```

or the whole Chart:

```
zedGraphControl1.IsAntiAlias = true;
```

All examples are taken [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287666/isantialias-creates-border-around-graph).

Comment: Yay!!!, I think it works now, Thank you so much buddy.  Just another point that I also discovered in case anybody else has the same problem.  There is a function lineItem.Line.isAntiAlias which handles the pixellation from the zedgraphControl.

Comment: Yes, antialiasing can be turnened on for ZedGraph diagramms. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287666/isantialias-creates-border-around-graph)! It seems to be available at several levels.. - If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Comment: I found another problem in applying this method. The print out pdf size is huge. Is there anyway we can scale the output so that the quality for 300x300dpi still apply? I only have half a page to fit this image in

Comment: Hm, you need to check the numbers you get. Inserting a bitmap with 300 dpi should be honored by the pdf lib, but I'm not really familiat with it and its Scale function.. You your image is 1050, 1350 pixels?